# How to get last modification datetime on Sql Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there any way to get a table's last modification datetime on Sql Server 2005? Preferably without creating triggers..

And for databases?

*EDIT* The solution of this question contemplated only CREATE and ALTER modifications. For INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE please look [my next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227707/how-to-get-last-insert-update-delete-datetime-on-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will list all object types from most recent change to oldest, you can easily modify as necessary...

```
DECLARE @SearchParams   varchar(500)
SET @SearchParams='yourObjectName'

SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(23),modify_date,121) AS modify_date
        ,type_desc
        ,name
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE is_ms_shipped=0 AND name LIKE '%'+@SearchParams+'%'
    ORDER BY modify_date DESC
```

if you just want tables, try:

```
DECLARE @SearchParams   varchar(500)
SET @SearchParams='YourTableName'
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(23),modify_date,121) AS modify_date
        ,type_desc
        ,name
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE type='U'
        AND name LIKE '%'+@SearchParams+'%' --can use "=@SearchParams" if you have the entire table name
    ORDER BY modify_date DESC
```

Comment: While it works, it wasn't what I expected. I'll rephrase the question.

Comment: rephrased and linked the rephrased question in the question body

Answer (score 1):

KM's solution will show when a table *object* (the table definition) was last modified. There is no built-in way to determine when the data within a give row was last updated (or inserted or, of course, deleted).  The only 99% reliable way I've ever found to do that is with triggers, with that missing 1% representing when some troublemaker disables the trigger.

Comment: from the OP's question, I was thinking "table modification"=table structure changes, thus my answer.  if "table modification"=insert/update/delete then @Philip Kelley is correct, you need a trigger, just watch out if you update a last changed row in antother table to track the changes, you may create blocking there.