# In SQL Server 2005, how can I see when a table has been created?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2005, is there any way to see when a table has been created?

And is there any way to see when was done the last `INSERT` in a table?

And what about the last `ALTER TABLE` date?

Thank you in advance for your kind cooperation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the creation and last modification date by querying `sys.tables`

```
SELECT  create_date, modify_date
FROM    sys.tables
```

AFAIK, there's no way out of the box to know when the last insert took place. You will have to restort to either using triggers or set up [auditing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on your tables.

Answer (score 2):

This query will give you the time and date when a table has been created and when it was last modified:

```
USE DataBaseName;
SELECT  [name]
        ,create_date
        ,modify_date
FROM    sys.tables
WHERE   [name] IN ('TableName1', 'TableName2');
```

Getting the last date of insertion is not so straightforward. Check out this StackOverflow question: [How to get last insert/update/delete datetime on Sql Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227707/how-to-get-last-insert-update-delete-datetime-on-sql-server-2005)