# "timestamp" for Tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know there is a `timestamp`/`rowversion` types you can set for a column.

Is there a similar property/field/mechanism for Tables, that can tell me if **Table rows** were modified (e.g. Row/s Inserted/Deleted/Updated)?

I can read the table schema but I can't see any column that present such information (if I for example open the Table schema with ADO - `DATE_MODIFIED` is always null - I'm also sure it refers to the Table structure, not rows Data).

I was thinking to create my own "Application" Table in which I will store this information which will be collected via creating Triggers in the tables I need to inspect. But this seems like a lot of effort if there is already a working pattern for this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227707/how-to-get-last-insert-update-delete-datetime-on-sql-server-2005 ?

Comment: You don't set the timestamp value.  Sql Server sets it.  Look at the answer to this post for an example.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116334/sql-server-2008-row-insert-and-update-timestamps

Comment: @granadaCoder, Yes, sorry, I used the wrong terminology.

Comment: @cubitouch, In the link you provided, the accepted answer does not give the results I need (nor What the OP in that question asked for) i.e. "Latest datetime when a table/database had an *insert/update/delete*"). It does show changes if the table structure itself was changes. (I'll check again, maybe I missed something)

Comment: I think you are wrong, see this (linked to the previous answer) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190283.aspx, it seems to me that can retrieve index date creation (which is ok for insert, I think, maybe you can try something for Update)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that there is no `timestamp` / `rowversion` that applies to a table.

You could create a table of modifications as you suggest.  You could trap any INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statement with a trigger and INSERT the date/time of the modification.  However, this date/time does not tell you *what* changed-- only that *something* changed.  That limitation may be acceptable for you.

If you need to know more information about what changed, you could use a `timestamp` or modification date column on each record.  Have the application code record the last known maximum timestamp or change date.  Then it becomes easy to query for changed records.  This should also remove the need for a separate table to track modification dates.

Unfortunately, you cannot tell exactly which rows were deleted in this manner.  If you need to track deleted rows, too, you may need to use a `DELETE` trigger to record them in a table.

-- EDIT --

Microsoft added [change tracking and change data capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx) starting with SQL Server 2008.  I have never used this feature, so I have no recommendation regarding it.  However, the feature is available in [SQL Server Standard Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx), so you don't have to buy the Enterprise Edition to get it.

To use change tracking, first configure the database to use change tracking:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON (CHANGE_RETENTION = 14 DAYS)
```

Next, configure which tables you want to track:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
```

To get the latest version, use [CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933945%28v=sql.120%29.aspx):

```
DECLARE @version BIGINT
SET @version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION();

SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

To get the changes since the last version, use the [CHANGETABLE function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933874.aspx).  Using a LEFT JOIN ensures the query returns information about deleted rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES MyTable, @version) C
LEFT JOIN MyTable T
    ON T.ID = C.ID
```

Note that Microsoft recommends using snapshot isolation:

> Choosing the approach that will work for the application when you are
>   using change tracking (or any custom tracking mechanism), requires
>   significant analysis. Therefore, it is much simpler to use snapshot
>   isolation.